# Please help me translate the poem on my dizia into english

Tags: translation, traditional-characters, poetry

can someone help me translate this poem? Tried google translate but it was a total mess

[image]

Comment: You may find this illuminating -- https://youtu.be/m4qo7wwMrkA

Answer (score 3):

It is a poem by 杜牧 (DU Mu)

Title: 將赴吳興登樂遊原

**清時有味是無能，閒愛孤雲靜愛僧**。

**欲把一麾江海去，樂遊原上望昭陵**。

Author: 杜牧

> 289 杜牧 – [將赴吳興登樂遊原](https://28utscprojects.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/289/) (DU Mu – Mounting the Leyou Tombs Before Departing for Wuxing)

English Translation﹕

> Only the incompetent would laze away peaceful times, I'd stare at a lone cloud when idle, and seek a monk's company for peace and quiet.

> Now I'm about to trudge over rivers and seas to a corner administer,
> Here on Leyou Tombs my tribute goes to Emperor Taizong.